# How to use $and in $match query with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My query now is

```
events = mdb.events.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"type": "ClientService"}},
        {"$project": {"value": 1, "day": {"$dayOfYear": "$timestamp"}, "count": {"$add": [1]}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": {"day": "$day", "value": "$value"}, "count": {"$sum": "$count"}}},
        {"$sort": {"day": -1, "value": 1}}
    ])
```

How to modify this query to use "$and" statement in $match query to find documents by more than one parameter?

Comment: So what does your document look like? And exactly which fields do you want to include?

Comment: Just add another element like so: `{"$match": {"type": "ClientService", "some_field": "Awesomesauce"}},` The default operator is `$and` so explicit `$and` is needed rarely.

Answer (score 1):

From MongoDB docs.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

Anyways the syntax for the '$and' remains the same in aggregation
i.e.

`{ $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }`

So your query will look like

```
events = mdb.events.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"$and" : [{"type": "ClientService"},{"some_key":"value"}]}},
    {"$project": {"value": 1, "day": {"$dayOfYear": "$timestamp"}, "count": {"$add": [1]}}},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"day": "$day", "value": "$value"}, "count": {"$sum": "$count"}}},
    {"$sort": {"day": -1, "value": 1}}
])
```

The same is true for `$or`,`$not`, `$ne` etc.